# Perl shift returns passed parameters vs. shift() function which returns first element

Tags: perl

I see `shift` used in two contexts:

1. When it is used to obtain the parameters passed to a subroutine

   ```
   sub somesub (%) {
     my %params = shift;
     # All parameters now in %params.
     my $filename = $params{'FILE'};
     my @args = @{$params{'ARGS'}};
   }
   ```
2. When it is used to return the first element in an array

   ```
   $elm = shift(@array)
   ```

Is the `shift` in the first case the same function?

I've also seen it used in subroutines without parameters. What does it mean in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same function. Without an argument, `shift` defaults to use `@_`, which is the array which contains the parameters passed to the script or function.

Comment: Also note that most Perl functions use `@_` and `$_` when no argument is given.

Comment: Not quite. Inside a subroutine, `shift` with no arguments acts on `@_`. Outside a subroutine (and in a few other contexts), it acts on `@ARGV`, not `@_`. `perldoc -f shift` or http://perlmaven.com/perldoc/shift

Comment: @chepner, are you sure about this answer? testing his first sub by passing a hash resulted in the odd elements error. Shouldn't it be `my %params = @_` to get the behavior he is looking for?

Comment: @Gabs00: It is the OP's example that is wrong, not this answer.

Comment: Well, one would expect the answer to cover the misuse of `shift` in the code.